# why my password validation code is not working?

Tags: javascript, html

i've made a trail login page but when i'm trying to validate the password...nothing is showing up..
Heres my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cmdvalidate()
    {  
        if(form1.pass.value==form1.c_pass.value) {
            if(form1.pass.length<=6) {
                alert("password length must be greater than 6!!");

                form1.pass.value="";
                form1.c_pass.value="";                   
            } else {
                document.write("<font color="red" size=4><br>*password matched successfully<br></font>");
                document.write("Submit you form<br>");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Password not matched!!");

            form1.pass.value="";
            form1.c_pass.value="";
        }         
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What *does* happen in this code?  Where are the password values coming from?  Is there a JavaScript error on the browser's development console?  When you use the browser's debugger, is this function invoked at all?  When you step through the function in the browser's debugger, what specifically happens?

Comment: From where do you get `form1`?

Comment: please try to attach a working example

Comment: Where is `form1` coming from?

Comment: Also, could you attach your html form?

Comment: The code as posted has a syntax error that would prevent anything at all from happening. Beyond that, using `document.write()` after the page has loaded is a mistake anyway.

Comment: Stepping thru your code should figure this one out. if u r not sure how check out this link. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/step-code without more of the code I don't think anyone can fully solve your issue further. like what is form1 and pass. how r u calling cmdvalidate()?

Comment: I am calling the function cmdvalidate() under body tag...after accepting values from user <form name="form1" method="post" action="mailto:example.mail@gmail.com"> ............<input type="button" onclick="cmdvalidate ()" value="check password"> </form>

Comment: @Pointy I've some doubt...Why document.write() is  a mistake??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a little snippet demonstrating an alternative to your approach. You should not use the old form of addressing form elements through `formname.elementId` but should use the new `document.querySelector()` or one of the `document.getElementById()` or `document.getElementsBy...()` methods instead.

Also note the way I bound the event listener to the `<body>` element and deferred its action to `INPUT:password` elements only.

```js
const qs=s=>document.querySelector(s);  // define a little shortcut here ...

qs('body').addEventListener('keyup',e=>{
 if ((e.target.tagName+e.target.type).toLowerCase()=="inputpassword"){
  var p1=qs('#pass').value, p2=qs('#c_pass').value;
  var btnstyle=qs('#go').style;
  with (qs('.msg')) 
    if(p1!=p2){
      innerHTML='passwords differ ...';
      btnstyle.visibility='hidden';
    }
    else {
     if (p1.length>6) {
       innerHTML='';
       btnstyle.visibility='visible'
     ;}
     else innerHTML='password must be longer 6 characters'
    }
}});
```

```css
.msg {color:red; font-size:0.8em}
#go {visibility:hidden}
```

```html
<form name="form1">
<label>Please define your password here:<br>
 <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass"><br>
 <input type="password" name="c_pass" id="c_pass">
 <input type="submit" value="submit" id="go">
</label>
<div class="msg"></div>
</form>
```